# read a text file with python with /t /n

Tags: python, text-files, delimiter, readfile, readline

I have a text file for exemple:

```
1 2 3

4 5 6 7

8 9
```

I want to get the output `[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]`.

I tried the following code:

```py
with open('name_file.txt', 'r') as f:
  text=f.readlines()
```

But I got the following output:

```
 '1\t2\t3\n',
 '4\t5\t6\t7\n',
 '8\t9\n',
```

Comment: Yes - you've read lines that contain tab characters and have line endings.

Comment: Have a look into the _pandas_ package it is great for reading, analyising and saving tabular data in various formats.

Comment: @Jacob You absolutely don't need Pandas to read a simple file of tab-separated numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If `.readlines()` shows you

```
[
  '1\t2\t3\n',
  '4\t5\t6\t7\n',
  '8\t9\n',
]
```

you're seeing the lines with line endings intact (since the newline character's escape representation is `\n`), and your numbers are separated by tabs (whose representation is `\t`).

You might want

```
my_list = []
with open('name_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        my_list.append([int(value) for value in line.strip().split()])
```

which will read the file line-by-line (iterating over a file does that), remove all leading and trailing spaces from each line (`strip()`), split the line using all remaining whitespace (so this will work for both tabs and spaces or a combination thereof), and finally use `int()` to convert the strings to integers.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a file called `data.txt` with the following contents:

```
1   2   3
4   5   6   7
8   9
```

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to parse each line along with [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split):

```
data = []
with open('data.txt') as data_file:
    for line in data_file:
        data.append([int(x) for x in line.split()])
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
```